# Adding ECW file to MXD with ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, ecw

I'm using Desktop 10.2 and I tried ,with this script, to add ecw file to mxd's but the result is a black & white raster(stretched symbology) instead of colored raster(RGB composite symbology) :

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping
import os
import sys
from arcpy import env
import string


env.workspace = r"C:\project"
for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
  print mxd
  mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\project\\" + mxd)
  df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapdoc, "Layers")[0]
  Layer1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\project\layers\F1292_KVISH6_25CM_.ecw")
  arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df ,Layer1 )
  mapdoc.save()
del mxd # i added
```

this is the image i get:
[image: black & white image]

i don't know how to changed the python script so i will get RGB colored image ?

Comment: When you use `Add Data` from within ArcMap, do you get the colored raster displaying correctly? Or is it black and white as well?

Comment: i get colored raster correctly.see artwork21 answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually save a layer file of the raster in the r g b format.  Then, use the same code  as you did, but reference the saved .lyr file instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Make Raster Layer Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006t000000) rather than `arcpy.mapping.Layer`:

> Creates a raster layer from an input raster dataset or layer file. The
>   layer that is created by the tool is temporary and will not persist
>   after the session ends unless the layer is saved to disk or the map
>   document is saved.
>
> This tool can be used to make a temporary layer, so you can work with
>   a specified subset of bands within a raster dataset.

Comment: That link doesn't work for me.

Comment: Fixed link. Try again.